# I get psycopg2 syntax error at end of input when executing

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I get a psycopg2 syntax error at end of input when im exectuing the query and i cant figure it out. I tried to write the query inside the execture function for it didnt helped.
I searched the solution for my case on the web but nothing helped..

The ERROR is :
syntax error at or near ""                              ""
LINE 1: ...                      " WHERE first_name = 'Eyal' "         ...
^

```
select_query = """ SELECT first_name, value " \
                         "FROM PATIENTS " \
                         " WHERE first_name = %s " \
                         " AND valid_start_time IN (SELECT MAX(valid_start_time) " \
                                                    " FROM PATIENTS " \
                                                    " WHERE first_name = %s AND " \
                                                    " valid_start_time::DATE = %s " \
                                                    " AND transaction_time::DATE < %s """


          cursor.execute(select_query, (first_name, first_name, wanted_date[0], prespective_date,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing the last closing parenthesis (one that'd close the `SELECT MAX(...)` subquery), hence "syntax error at end of input".

```
select_query = """
SELECT first_name, value
FROM PATIENTS
WHERE first_name = %s AND valid_start_time IN (
  SELECT MAX(valid_start_time)
  FROM PATIENTS
  WHERE first_name = %s AND valid_start_time::DATE = %s AND transaction_time::DATE < %s
)
"""
```

should work better (and using a single `"""` string is more readable if you ask me).

Comment: I cant believe i didnt saw it! Thank you very much :)